# Find r and n in congruence $827. 3^{839} ≡ r \mod n$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Edit: Find r and n in congruence $827. 3^{839} ≡ r \mod n$

I am new to this modulo arithmetic topic and was given a question to solve.

> Find $n$ in the following equation:
>   $$3^{839}\equiv827\bmod n$$

I have tried finding $3^{128}$ and thought of using the power laws to solve this equation but still unable to find $n$.

I am stuck and do not know how to proceed on any further.

Comment: Trivially, you can have $n = 3^{839} - 827$.  Without further information, this does not look like a good problem to consider for me.  Voting to close.

Comment: I took a guess and 1615 seems to work.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris You would get a complete answer is you had instead said "$n$ is a divisor of $3^{839}-827$". Considering $827$ is prime and addition / subtraction usually makes factoring difficult, I think trial and error will be the best way to get one answer if that's all you want ($n = 2$ seems to work, for instance).

Answer (score 2):

839 is prime so using Fermat little theorem we can write:

$3^{839-1}≡1 \mod 839$

Multiplying both sides be 827 we get:

$827\times 3^{838}≡827 \mod 827\times 839≡827\mod 839$

So n can be equal to:

$n=839$  and $839\times 827=693853$

Comment: @coffee, please correct your question to avoid down vote; the correct form of question is: Find r and n in following congruence:$827. 3^{839}≡ r \mod n$